# Using limit clause along with union all or selecting top 2 and last 3 results 

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a query which can select top 2 and last 3 results of the same table with same field name.
I have tried `UNION ALL` in every possible way I can.

I'm using MYSQL and PHP.

## From OP's comment:

```
select * 
    from tbl_product asc 
union 
select * 
    from tbl_product desc 
    order by pd_price limit 2
```

Comment: select * from tbl_product asc
union
select * from tbl_product  desc
order by pd_price limit 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your problem focuses on how to logically sum two data sets coming from the same entity, ordered by the same criteria (price, as you mentioned).

The first data set has to consider just the first two records, while the second data set has to consider the last three.

First of all, you should enclose into aliases the two subqueries.

Then, for the second alias you may choose to double encapsulate it, to take advantage of ascending order.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl_product
    ORDER BY pd_price ASC
    LIMIT 2
) tbl1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_product
        ORDER BY pd_price DESC
        LIMIT 3
    ) tbl_a
    ORDER BY pd_price ASC
) tbl2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, top 2 and last 3 depends on your requirement as its not mentioned as top lowest products. Do u consider top 2 as the product with highest price and last 3 as with lowest or viceversa. I am assuming case1.

```
select *
        from (
            SELECT * 
                FROM `tbl_product`
                order by pd_price desc limit 2
        ) as t1

union all

select *
    from (
        SELECT * 
            FROM `tbl_product`
            order by pd_price asc limit 3
    )  as t2
```

Comment: I have tried this query structure also(exactly same), gave me an error "incorrect usage of UNION ALL and ORDER BY". :D

Comment: no its different, try to execute it. You get that error when you dont put those into alias whereas i hv done that.

Comment: Alas! just to take advantage of ascending order my solution was neglected rather than for the core necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using stored procedures or mysqli_multi_query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_table` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT `field` FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 2;
INSERT INTO tmp_table SELECT `field` FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3;
SELECT field FROM tmp_table;
```

P.S. Sorry for my English:)